# Does the group of compactly supported diffeomorphisms have the homotopy type of a CW complex?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

It is known that the group of diffeomorphisms of a compact manifold with the natural $C^{\infty}$ topology has the homotopy type of a countable CW complex. See for instance this thread: [Is the space of diffeomorphisms homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126829/is-the-space-of-diffeomorphisms-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-cw-complex)

The group $Diff_c(M)$ of compactly supported diffeomorphisms is a nuclear LF space: [http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf)
With this topology does it have the homotopy type of a CW complex?

Comment: I don't know a reference but presumably there is one.  You get a similar argument these diffeomorphism groups embed as open subsets of the Hilbert cube, and the result follows from that.

Comment: Don't you need at least Frechet for this? This is not a Frechet group.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realised that you are not working with a nonstandard, nonmetrisable topology on $Diff_c(M)$. Maybe you can explain where in Michor's monograph the manifold structure are topology on $Diff_c(M)$ are defined.

Comment: There is no natural Frechet structure on Diff_c so I am not sure what you mean by non-standard.

Comment: By results of Shkarin, a strict inductive limit of a sequence of metrisable, locally convex TVS's is stratifiable. By results of Borges, every locally convex TVS belongs to AE(stratifiable). Thus any *strict* LF space is stratifiable and AR(stratifiable). It follows that any paracompact manifold modeled on a *strict* LF space is stratifiable and ANR(stratifiable), and hence has CW homotopy type.

Comment: Can you write it as a complete answer please, with explanation of the terms and references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll explain the claim left in the comments - namely that any paracompact manifold modeled on a strict LF space has CW homotopy type. The notion of an LF space is not completely standard across the literature, so to be clear, I will understand a *strict LF space* to be a locally convex TVS $E$ which is obtained as the inductive limit (in the category of locally convex TVS's) of an increasing sequence of continuous, linear, proper, closed embeddings of Fréchet spaces
$$E_1\subseteq E_2\subseteq E_3\subseteq\dots$$
Since the linked monograph doesn't seem to contain any discussion of $Diff_c(M)$, I'm afraid that I really don't know if this is applicable to whatever structure on it that you have in mind.

In the sequel I will make use of spaces which are *stratifiable* in the sense of Borges [2]. Every metric space is stratifiable, and every stratifiable space is a paracompact, perfectly normal Hausdorff $\sigma$-space. The property of stratifiability is equivalent to the $M_2$ (equivalently $M_3$) property of Ceder [4], and this makes the following easy to prove.

> **Proposition**: A paracompact space which is locally stratifiable is stratifiable. $\quad\blacksquare$

A space $Y$ is an AE(stratifiable) (ANE(stratifiable)) if for any stratifiable space $X$ and any closed subspace $A\subseteq X$, any map $f:A\rightarrow Y$ has an extension to $X$ (to a neighbourhood of $A$ in $X$). A stratifiable space $X$ is said to be an an AR(stratifiable) (ANR(stratifiable)) if whenever it is embedded in a stratifiable space as a closed subset, then it is a retract (neighbourhood retract) there.

> **Proposition**: The following statements hold.
>
> 1. AR(stratifiable) $\Rightarrow$ ANR(stratifiable) and AE(stratifiable) $\Rightarrow$ ANE(stratifiable).
> 2. The property of being ANE(stratifiable) is open-hereditary.
> 3. A stratifiable space is an AR(stratifiable) (ANR(stratifiable)) if and only if it is an AE(stratifiable) (ANR(stratifiable)).
> 4. A paracompact space which is locally an ANE(stratifiable) is an ANE(stratifiable). $\quad\blacksquare$

A metric space is an ANE(stratifiable) if and only if it is an ANR(metric). Every CW complex is stratifiable and an ANR(stratifiable). The relevance of this class of spaces to your question is the following.

> **Theorem**: The following statements about a space $X$ are equivalent.
>
> 1. $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex.
> 2. $X$ has the homotopy type of a simplicial complex.
> 3. $X$ has the homotopy type of a metric space which is an ANR(metric).
> 4. $X$ has the homotopy type of a stratifiable space which is an ANR(stratifiable). $\quad\blacksquare$

The equivalence of the first three bullet points is well known. The fact that they are equivalent to the fourth is a corollary of Théorème 1.5 in Cauty [3].

The following extends the classical Dugundji Theorem, which states that every locally convex TVS is an AE(metric).

> **Theorem (Borges [1])**: Every locally convex TVS is an AE(stratifiable). $\quad\blacksquare$

Now, this theorem covers strict LF spaces, which are therefore AE(stratifiable). Strict LF spaces are never metrisable, but there is the following more general result of Shkarin, which implies their stratifiability.

> **Theorem (Shkarin [5, Co.5])**: A strict inductive limit of a sequence of metrisable, locally convex TVS's is stratifiable. $\quad\blacksquare$

Combining the last two results yields the following.

> **Corollary**: A strict inductive limit of a sequence of metrisable, locally convex TVS's is an AR(stratifiable).  $\quad\blacksquare$

I want to clear that Shkarin defines a *strict inductive limit* in the same way that I have previously. Namely, as the inductive limit of a sequence of *closed*, continuous, linear inclusions.

> **Corollary**: Any paracompact manifold modeled on a strict LF space has the homotopy type of a CW complex.

**Proof**: Any manifold $X$ modeled on TVS which is the strict inductive limit of a sequence of metrisable, locally convex TVS's is locally stratifiable and locally an ANE(stratifiable). If $X$ is paracompact, then it is a stratifiable ANE(stratifiable), and hence an ANR(stratifiable). It follows from Cauty's Theorem that $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex. $\quad\blacksquare$

**Remarks**

- We have openly established something more general than claimed.
- A stratifiable spaces is separable if and only if it is Lindelöf. Hence if $X$ in the last statement is separable, then it is homotopy equivalent to a countable CW complex.

**References**:

[1]. C. Borges, *A Study of Absolute Extensor Spaces*, Pacific J. Math. **31**(3) (1969) 609-617.

[2]. C. Borges, *On stratifiable spaces*, Pacific J. Math. **17**(1) (1966) 1-16.

[3] R. Cauty, *Rétractions dans Les espaces dtratifiables*, Bulletin de la S.M.F., tome **102** (1974), 129-149.

[4] J. Ceder, *Some generalizations of metric spaces*,  Pacific J. Math. **11**(1) (1961) 105-125 .

[5]. S. Shkarin, *On stratifiable locally convex spaces*, Russian J. Math. Phys., **6** (1999), 435-460.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. What is a separable stratifiable space in this context?

Comment: @Yasha I'm glad it was useful to you. Separable here just means having a countable dense set.

Comment: I see, in our case the relevant space $Diff_c(M)$ is separable. So you have proved it has the homotopy type of a countable CW complex. I don't know if you want to add this to your answer.